# apache not running XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp

I am using Bitnami XAMPP on windows 7. It has been more than a year i'm using, but today all of a sudden it is showing Apache shutdown unexpectedly error.

> Attempting to start Apache app... 
> 9:43:46 PM  [Apache]   Status change
>   detected: running 
> 9:43:47 PM  [Apache]   Status change detected:
>   stopped 
> 9:43:47 PM  [Apache]     Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
>   
> 9:43:47 PM  [Apache]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing
>   dependencies,  
> 9:43:47 PM  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or
>   a shutdown by another method. 
> 9:43:47 PM  [Apache]   Press the Logs
>   button to view error logs and check 
> 9:43:47 PM  [Apache]     the Windows
>   Event Viewer for more clues 
> 9:43:47 PM  [Apache]     If you need more
>   help, copy and post this 
> 9:43:47 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on
>   the forums

Please note that Skype is not running, and i even tried changing the port to 81 by editing httpd.conf. Still I have unchecked "use port 80 and 443 or additional incoming connections" 
After changing port number to 81 I went to Command prompt and used command

```
netstat -nab
```

I did not get any applications using port 81. I'm done restarting XAMPP and my computer.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this I have the same issue.  Netstat does not show my ports being blocked, Skype can be running or not running.

Comment: @Eoin I got it resolved when I re installed XAMPP. I couldn't figure out what exactly was the problem though.

Comment: This was caused by Bitnami!  They added a line to the bottom of my apache httpd.conf file.  Suckers.  I won't be using that way of installing again, there are loads of things I hated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the port using the Xampp Control Panel?

Comment: have you tried to run Xampp Control Panel as Admin?

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here.

It seems related to a blocked port. Try to change from the XAMPP Control Panel the both http and https ports in all the Apache configuration files.

To do that, press Config on the Apache section, and change the ports in httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf

You need also change the service port: Config (button on the right corner) -> Service and Ports Settings.

Click Netstat button if you want to see the currently used ports.

I hope it helps

David

Comment: I resolved it myself by uninstalling a recently installed software which was the probable reason for the error.